# Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'username', table 'FERA_ONL_LEARNING.dbo.Account'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails

Tags: java, sql-server, web, netbeans

I have the following code:

```
 public void updateAccount(String username, String name, String address, String aboutMe, 
 String id) {
    String sql = "update Account set username = ?, \n"
            + "                [Full_Name] = ?,\n"
            + "                [Address] = ?,\n"
            + "                [about_me] = ?\n"
            + "                where id = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.setString(3, address);
        ps.setString(4, aboutMe);
        ps.setString(5, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

But when I change something like username, fullname in my web, they are still not updated and show the following error:

> Severe:   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into
> column 'username', table 'FERA_ONL_LEARNING.dbo.Account'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
> fails. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:328)
> at dao.AccountDao.updateAccount(AccountDao.java:142)
> at controller.UserProfileController.doPost(UserProfileController.java:91)

I'm sure I changed their values and it can't be NULL.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the result of your dynamic query? You could add a system.out.println(sql) before ps.executeUpdate(), to verify that your variables are being assigned the value correctly.

I estimate by how the sql is concatenated that it is not taking the positions correctly and by default the setString returns NULL.